Ctrl+Y in PyCharm is supposed to delete the line where the caret is, but it's not working
I'm experiencing an issue in PyCharm where the shortcut Ctrl+Y, which is supposed to delete the line where the caret (text cursor) is located, isn't functioning as expected. The shortcut isn't deleting the line, and I’m unsure why this is happening. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and how can it be resolved? documentation-link
I tried to tune some settings but no use.
